# Does Czernobog have anything to do with the number 7?

Tags: slavic, numerology

I know Czernobog, the Slavic god of darkness, mainly from Neil Gaiman's novel "American Gods". There is a scene in which Czernobog, Anansi (African spider god and trickster) and Shadow (the son of the Norse god Odin) each move into a motel room. Czernobog gets number seven, Anansi number eight, and Shadow number nine.

As for the other two, I understand the allusions - a spider has eight legs, and Odin hung on the Yggdrasil tree for nine days and nights. But what about Czernobog and the Seven?

Comment: Are you sure there are actually allusions being made there? The link between Shadow and 9 seems rather indirect, and it would work just as well for 1, 2 or 8 (Odin had one eye, two ravens, and an eight-legged horse). But, if such indirect connections are allowed, someone can probably find a way to link Czernobog to 7. Come to think of it, his name ends with the 7th letter of the alphabet.

Comment: Three and four make 7
Evil 3 and the physical world 4 make the illusion of seven. Do not be fooled by false gods(actors in the physical world making you worship them.